# How to pdftk end minus 1?

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I want to exctact pages from a pdf document such that all pages are extracted except the first one and the last one. 
Code but `(end-1)` does not work, nor `2-end-1`

```
pdftk 1.pdf cat 2-(end-1) output output.pdf
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
pdftk yourpdfile.pdf cat 2-r2 output out.pdf
```

From the documentation:

> You can reference page numbers in reverse order by prefixing them with the letter r. For example, page r1 is the last page of the document, r2 is the next-to-last page of the document, and rend is the first page of the document. You can use this prefix in ranges, too, for example r3-r1 is the last three pages of a PDF.

Comment: Works great, also with multiples documents: `pdftk A=first.pdf B=second.pdf cat A2-r2 Br1 output out.pdf`

Answer (score 8):

You can define a range and remove pages from it (using `~`) to achieve this:

```
pdftk 1.pdf cat 2-end~end output output.pdf
```

This tells `pdftk cat` to take the pages from the second page to the last page included (`2-end`), and remove the last page from the range (`~end`). The result is a PDF containing everything apart from the first and last pages of the original.

Comment: @Assume you need to remove last page and one before last page i.e. two pages at the end. Is that possible with your approach?

Comment: No, not with this approach; you need Rakesh's reverse approach for that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following format:

```
pdftk A=1.pdf cat A2-(n-1) output 'outputfile_p2-p(n-1).pdf'
```

You can determine `n` through:

```
pdftk 1.pdf dump_data | grep NumberOfPages
```

e.g.: `n=8`

```
pdftk A=1.pdf cat A2-7 output 'outputfile_p2-p7.pdf'
```

Comment: How do you determine `n`?

Comment: A pdf document with `n` pages

Comment: I get `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('` with your syntax. What is your shell?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 the `/bin/bash`

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 run the following `pdftk A=1.pdf cat A2-7 output 'outfile_p2-p7.pdf'`

Comment: @GAD3R That syntax works but there is no exclusion by one at the end.

Comment: I meant programmatically...

Comment: Programmatically would be: `n=$(pdftk 1.pdf dump_data | grep NumberOfPages | cut -d ":" -f 2)` and you can use it than like that: `$(expr $n - 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Following the idea of [@GADR3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355011/122663) you could solve it programmatically by setting the number of pages to `n`:

```
n=$(pdftk 1.pdf dump_data | grep NumberOfPages | cut -d ":" -f 2)
```

And then use `n` as an expression for the `pdftk` command:

```
pdftk A=1.pdf cat A2-$(expr $n - 1) output output.pdf
```

---

Personally, I prefer to use the reverse order prefix `r` as described in [@user218374](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355014/122663) answer:

```
pdftk A=1.pdf cat A2-r2 output output.pdf
```